# Pular resultado no foreach a cada dois resultados

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

Tenho alguns resultados no banco e preciso alinhar eles de acordo com a imagem abaixo. Mas não consegui. Estou fazendo em Laravel 5.8.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="0">
      <tbody>
        @foreach ($equipe as $key => $a)
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 50%;">
            <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>{{$a->admin->name}}</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center;">Controladora Municipal</p>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 50%;">
            <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>{{$a->admin->name}}</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center;">Controladora Municipal</p>
          </td>
        </tr>   
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

É como se a cada 2 resultados do foreach eu pudesse encaixar na tabela. Como consigo alinhar o resultado do foreach asssim?

Comment: Parece que está confundindo front-end e back-end, se os dados do back-end estão vindo conforme o esperado, o alinhamento é estilo.

Comment: eu preciso reproduzir esse resultado da imagem.. sabe como posso fazer? Tentei usando um break, etc...

Comment: Break? Eu acredito que tenha que editar a questão e adicionar as tags CSS, Flex-Grid, Flex-box... Coloca o resultado que tem...

Comment: queria saber como eu faria isso no html então...

Comment: Então, na verdade precisa analisar a estrutura. Isso que quer me parece mais com uma lista `<ul>` do que com tabela... O que quer é exatamente uma tabela? Tem outros campos? Pois aí se tem 2 linhas e 2 colunas do mesmo tipo de dado. Algo de errado parece não estar certoX)

Comment: Provável que você tenha bootstrap no projeto, caso tenha dê uma olhada em [grids](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works). Já facilitando sua vida, provavelmente você ira ter que usar 6 colunas, ficando algo como: `col-sm-6` nas classes.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, João. Tudo bem?
Me parece que sua dúvida está mais relacionada à html/css que propriamente à php/laravel.

De qualquer forma, para a sua questão, imaginando que você espera receber os valores sempre na mesma posição, devido à descrição do cargo estar escrito de forma estática , como mostra esta linha

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Controladora Municipal</p>
```

Pode-se facilmente acessar a posição dos elementos do array e inserir diretamente em  seu html. Ficaria algo como:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>{{$equipe[0]->admin->name}}</strong></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">Controladora Municipal</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 50%;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>{{$equipe[1]->admin->name}}</strong></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">Controladora Municipal</p>
      </td>
    </tr>     
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Claro que isso é apenas mais uma forma de acessar essa informação e, nesse caso, não precisaria do foreach.

Outra observação que faria era não usar tabela para esse tipo de dado.
Essa informação poderia ser facilmente estruturada com uma das opções:

- Bootstrap grid system - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
- Flexbox - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/